# Zero height with line-height and display: flex in Google Chrome v84

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

`line-height` and `display: flex` in Google Chrome v84 (Chrome v83 and FireFox seem fine) apparently doesn't enforce height of the element sometimes.

```html
<div class="outer-wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="inner">
      This text should display outside the wrapper box
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.outer-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper {
  line-height: 100px;
}

.inner {
  position: relative;
  top: 100%; // this seems ignored in Chrome v84 (perhaps .wrapper's height is 0)
}
```

Codepen to reproduce this issue: https://codepen.io/damhonglinh/full/BajMBNM

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems because of the combination of `display: flex` of `.outer-wrapper` and `line-height` of `.wrapper`.

So I guess a quick solution is to break that combination, by changing to use `display: block` or set `height` to `.wrapper` element.